# How can we do operation on the elements of the different cells?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix in size `10000 x 1`. With use of
`num2cell (reshape (E, 100, 100), 1)`
I split it into `100` cells with `100` elements. Now I want to perform operations on elements of each cell to make new elements and then gather all the new elements in a `10000*1` matrix.

Can I use "for" loop to do operations on elements of each cell? If yes how can I do that? And how can I gather all new elements in one matrix?

Comment: Why do you need it to be in a cell. What is this "operation"?

Comment: this operation contains some lines of code that Categories of data, split them, counting them, fitting with 7 order polynomial and get new data. about being in cell, I thought maybe its a good idea because I need totally split data and do all these procedure Separately on them.

Comment: Right but none of that requires cells, why not just operate on the rows and/or columns of your reshaped version of `E`?

Comment: at the end you want to gather *all new elements in one matrix*, so why do you want to convert your matrix into a cell in the first place? Provide a small example of what exactly you're upto!

Comment: ok, maybe putting them in the cells is not a good idea :); but what I want to do is: for example I have a matrix: `E=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]`, I need to split it like: `[1;2][3;4][5;6][7;8][9;10]`. then I should do all the operation separately on each of them to get new elements like: `[21;22][23;24][25;26][27;28][29;30]` and then gather them to get `[21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30]`

Comment: Reshape into an appropriate 2D matrix with each row being a "cell", operate on each row separately, then reshape back to the vector.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It works but that make other problems, I don’t know, can I ask question in here or I should present another question?

Answer (score 0):

use cellfun.

Example: for [1,2] => [21, 22]

```
E ={[1,2]};
fun = @(x) x+20; % add 20 to each element inside the cell
output = cellfun(@(x) fun(x),E,'uniformoutput',false);
```